TYPO3 - Typoscript: How to get a field from tt_content as value into lib.contentElement?
In tt_content I added a new field in my sitepackage. Purpose: Add a css-class in the rendered content element. Now I have the problem how to get the value of this field into the typoscript setup.
# Get value for frameAttributes from field tx_dta_site_shadows in tt_content
lib.shadowSettings = COA
lib.shadowSettings {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        data = field:tx_dta_site_shadows
    }
}

# Extend frameAttributes typoscript from bk2k/bootstrap-package in sitepackage
lib.contentElement {
    dataProcessing {
        1682424577 {
            data {
                    class < lib.shadowSettings.10.data
                }
            }
        }
    }

The rendered result is:
<div class="field:tx_dta_site_shadows frame frame-default etc...>

But it should be:
<div class="my-shadow-classname-from-tt-content-field frame frame-default etc...>

Can you point me in the right direction?
In use: Typo3 v12.4.16 with bk2k/bootstrap-package

May try to bring lib. shadowSettings.10 to the frontend to debug it. data isn't may be the field you want but lib.shadowSettings.10.value ?

The whole approach looks wrong to me as the field is already retrieved by lib.contentelement which just queries all records of a special colPos (default: 0).
So you could just use it like this (un-tested):
lib.contentElement {
    dataProcessing {
        1682424577 {
            data {
                class = TEXT
                class.field = tx_dta_site_shadows
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

I haven't checked if the data and class keys are correct, the essence is that you have the value already, about the rest you've to check.

In contrast with your approach you couldn't even reliable assure that the value of lib.shadowSettings belongs to the same record like lib.contentElement and it would need further work to make it reliable (using uid).
The issue that field:tx_dta_site_shadows is written in the output could be solved with LOAD_REGISTER, but that's superfluous as you would query the same records twice -- yes it's plural because like explained it queries all records with the same colPos.

Thank you, this was the solution. I was thinking to complicated...

If the field has been added to tt_content and you want to use it in Fluid/lib.contentElement, you don't need to do anything extra. The lib.contentElement automatically passes the tt_content data set to Fluid as array data.
To output your new field tx_dta_site_shadows in Fluid is therefore sufficient:
<p>field tx_dta_site_shadows: {data.tx_dta_site_shadows}</p>


Yes, that's correct. But I need to get the value into the bk2k/bootstrap_package which is the base for my site package. The dataprocessor #1682424577 generates additional frame attributes for Layout/Default.
